# How can I edit ansible-vault encrypted files in visual-studio-code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ansible-vault

I am using the command line tool ansible-vault and try to edit an encrypted file.

`EDITOR=code ansible-vault edit test.txt`

It is expected that code opens with the decrypted content in the editor. After saving ansible-vault should decrypt the (changed) buffer. Works much like editing a git commit message.

However, the buffer is empty. And changing/saving doesn't do much to the file.

I also tried it with vim and subl, which both worked as expected. What do I have to do to use visual-studio-code for the task?

Comment: If you want to do this directly in VS Code, you can install this extension, which allows to encrypt/decrypt vault files in VS Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dhoeric.ansible-vault

Comment: Sadly it doesn't allow to edit. I always think decrypt should never be used over edit...

Answer (score 20):

Found it out. I need to:

```
EDITOR='code --wait' ansible-vault edit test.txt
```

Comment: How do you save the edit back to the vault again? I tried just saving the tmp-file in Code, but to no avail.

Comment: I guess you will need to close the editor window or code completly , because simply saving is not enough.

Comment: Adding this to alias doesn't work..any reason why ??